# Unable to pass output of find to image magick

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick, xargs, gnu-findutils

For some images in a directory as follows:

```
Atlas_21YearNova59_add_main.png
Atlas_21YearNova59_add_mask.png 
Atlas_Activity_2022faith52_add_main.png
Atlas_Activity_2022faith52_add_mask.png
Atlas_ActivityQA02_add_main.png
Atlas_ActivityQA02_add_mask.png
```

I need to multiply the `main` image with the `mask` image as

```
magick Atlas_ActivityQA002_add_main.png Atlas_ActivityQA002_add_mask.png -compose multiply -composite 002.png
```

to do this for every image:

```
for i in `seq -w 1 100`
do 
    find -regextype sed -regex ".*"$i".*" | xargs -I {} magick {} -compose multiply -composite $i".png"
done
```

However instead of passing the `main` and `mask` image together, they are passed one by one. Using `-t` flag in `xargs`, the command being executed is

```
magick ./Atlas_ActivityQA002_add_main.png -compose multiply -composite 002.png
```

The output of

```
for i in `seq -w 1 10`
do 
    find . -regextype sed -regex ".*"$i".*" | xargs
done
```

is

```
./Atlas_21YearNova59_add_main.png ./Atlas_21YearNova59_add_mask.png  
./Atlas_ActivityQA02_add_main.png ./Atlas_ActivityQA02_add_mask.png
```

But the images are passed separtely when called with `magick`. How to fix this?

Comment: Why even bother running `find` and `xargs`? If you have `i` you can perfectly easily generate the two input filenames and output filename `in="Image_${i}_main.png"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you shifted the goal posts since the images are no longer a sequence, but still you just have to extract the "root name", which can be done easily in bash:

```
for f in *_main.png
do
    rootname=${f%%_main.png}
    magick ${rootname}_main.png ${rootname}_mask.png -compose multiply -composite ${rootname}.png
done
```

If you are using ksh, you can also extract the root name using the `basename` command:

```
for f in *_main.png
do
    rootname=$(basename $f _main.png)
    magick ${rootname}_main.png ${rootname}_mask.png -compose multiply -composite ${rootname}.png
done
```

In bash if you have multiple folders, you can still process all the files in one shot with:

```
# enable '**' matching
shopt -s globstar  
# All *_main.png in all directories below the current one
for f in **/*_main.png 
do
    # this keeps the directory
    rootname=${f%%_main.png}  
    # All files have a directory specification
    magick ${rootname}_main.png ${rootname}_mask.png -compose multiply -composite ${rootname}.png 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

can't you just

```bash
for x in `seq -w 001 100`
do
 magick Image_${x}_main.png Image_${x}_mask.png -compose multiply -composite ${x}.png
done
```

Comment: I can't do this is because I have multiple folders with hundreds of files with much different names preceding the number. Hence this approach would require to re execute for each name separately.